# Qt MainWindow with QOpenGLWIdget in Retina display displays wrong size

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl

I have a Qt application with a `MainWindow`.

I embed a `QOpenGLWidget` in it. Everything works fine until I start using an Apple Retina Display and run my app in High DPI mode: my `QOpenGLWidget` is just 1/4 of the size it was supposed to have (i.e., it only fills the bottom-left part of the area it is supposed to fill). This widget is displaying raw OpenGL data (actually, an OpenSceneGraph context)

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean with 1/4 of the size? Do you mean the widget is not filling its designated area or the content in the GL view is not filling the widget area? What are you displaying in the widget? Raw OpenGL? Maybe you can illustrate with a screenshot.

Comment: @ypnos changed the question to answer you. Thanks! :)

Comment: I understand. Then you are providing the right answer to your question, while vicrucann is also hinting at the right problem. I suggest you accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Found out that the best option for now, for OpenGL related widgets and events, is to use the `QPaintDevice::devicePixelRatio()` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html#devicePixelRatio)

This implies multiplying everything that uses pixel coordinates, i.e., mouse events, resizing events, and so on. Example:

```
void MyGLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height) {
  width *= Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio(); 
  height *= Application::desktop()->devicePixelRatio(); 

  ...
  // Continue with previous code

}
```

When running in low resolution mode in a Retina/HighDPI display, or when running in a regular display, this ratio is 1, so this seems portable to me.

Answer (score 3):

From [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) (section OsX),

> Note: The scaling is not applied to Open GL windows

I didn't try this approach on Mac, but it helped with the same issue on my Windows machine. I'm not sure if it's the best solution, though, there could be easier. Try and see if it works.

The main idea is to scale up your OpenGL content sizes manually.

**First**, Define the amount of scale to be performed. You can use the characteristic of *physical dot per inch*:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);    
int x = QApplication::desktop()->physicalDpiX();
int y = QApplication::desktop()->physicalDpiY();
// values 284 and 285 are the examples of reference values that we determined when DPI scaling was disabled
double scaleX = 284.0/double(x);
double scaleY = 285.0/double(y);
```

`physicalDpi*` makes possible to judge how many pixels we have for an inch. In order to define the scale, detect how much is reference value of density and then scale proportionally against the density of the physical device (next step).

**Second**, you have to use the `scaleX` and `scaleY` inside your `QOpenGLWidget` and make sure we manually scale:

- sizes such as `QOpenGLWidget::width()` and `QOpenGLWidget::height()` will turn into `this->width()*m_scaleX` and `this->height()*m_scaleY`
- mouse events coordinates, e.g., `event->x()*m_scaleX` and  `event->y()*m_scaleY`

Comment: Thank you! based on your answer, I was able to find `devicePixelRatio`, which I think does directly what I want

Comment: Glad it helped. The `devicePixelRation` looks neater indeed. I think the manually calculated `scaleX` and `scaleY` would be slightly more precise. For my machine they were 2.0 and ~2.02; while the `devicePixelRation` would provide the value of 2.0 for the both dimensions. Not sure how perceivable the difference is, but it's nice to have both options.