# How to set app to always `open in low resolution`

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl, retina-display

I have an application developed with Qt3D (which uses OpenGL) by Qt 5.11.3 and Xcode 9.4.1 build tools. App runs fine on Linux and Windows, but on macOS Retina display (10.14, Mojave), I observe:

[image: macOS Retina display observation]

There are two workarounds for the above observation:

1. Set Retina display to full native resolution (microscopically small) then open app which seems to look and function correctly. Then lower the resolution to something usable and app continues to work properly
2. Get info of the app and check the `open in low resolution` checkbox like this image from [a website](https://cdn.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/get-info-low-resolution.jpeg):

[image: 2nd workaround by app-info dialog checkbox]

I have studied [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39455504/3405291) but the posted solutions look more like a hack. And my app is a complex one, I cannot just simply multiply everything by a ratio. Is there any other solution for this? How can I force my app to `open in low resolution` on macOS, already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55820459/3405291)? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with OpenGL-related things, but what about enabling the [High DPI support](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html)? (TL;DR: add `qApp->setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)`).

Comment: @cbuchart Thanks =) I'm going to try it :)